# Jquery - Data from vertical to horizontal format

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y73kyf9w/)

The data from sql is stored in vertical format, i want to display it in horizontal format.

This is how data is stored in sql server :-
[image]

I am using angularjs `ui-grid` to display data http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro. I bring this data from sql with `ajax` so this is converted in `JSON` format.

```
var jqxhr = jq.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Main/getData",              
            data: { catId: catId },
            success: function (data) {                                
                var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
....
});
```

This is how i need the final data format.

```
 $scope.myData = [
{
   "EmployeeId": "1",
   "OTHINC1": "200",
   "OTHINC2": "100"
},
{
   "EmployeeId": "2",
   "OTHINC1": "300",
   "OTHINC2": "100"
}    
];
```

Comment: can you please paste the structure of sql data in json format returned from server through ajax call

Comment: from database you can do this easily.

Comment: @Amitesh yess...i have included that in Fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/y73kyf9w/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve - [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/y73kyf9w/1/) (see the console.log)

```
var formattedData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj;
    var matchedIndex = indexOfByProp(formattedData, data[i].EmployeeId, 'EmployeeId');
    if(matchedIndex === -1) { //new employee
        obj = {
            "EmployeeId" : data[i].EmployeeId
        };
        obj[data[i].FieldName] = data[i].Value;//adding value as a property
        formattedData.push(obj);

    } else { //add the new property to obj
        obj = formattedData[matchedIndex];
        obj[data[i].FieldName] = data[i].Value;
    }
}
console.log(formattedData);
function indexOfByProp(arr, val, prop) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i][prop] === val) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var result=[];
var indexes = data.map(function (el) {
      return el.EmployeeId;
    });
indexes=$.unique(indexes);
indexes.filter(Create);

function Create(element) {
     obj = {
                "EmployeeId" :element
            };
      for(x in data){
              if(data[x].EmployeeId == element){

                  obj[data[x].FieldName] = data[x].Value;//adding value as a property

      }
    }

      result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result);
```